# Dynamic QUERY range

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet and in one of the tabs I have a table with computed data from other tabs. This is small table with 11 columns. Row(1) is the Header row and Column A is the list of items, Column B to J is the types. Data consists of numbers only.

As the data is computed, time to time values in some of the columns thru B to J can be totally zero. I want to create a subset of this table with QUERY but constructing a dynamic range getting only the columns which has at least 1 value which is greater than zero.

I'm aware that a range can be created as an array like {A:A\B:B\D:D} but in my case I don't know which columns can have values of greater than zero and I don't want to take columns into the range which has completely zero values.

I have created an expression to concatenate this array value as a text in a cell, however I can't use it with the QUERY formula either with INDEX or TEXT functions. Table is like this:

**Items      TypeA TypeB TypeC TypeD**
Bronze       0     0     0     0
Silver       0     0     1     0
Gold         0     0     1     0
Titanimum    1     0     0     0

For this snapshot of table, I want to QUERY range to be *{A:A\B:B\D:D}*. However, as the data is computed, the table can be like this after 2hrs or the next day:

**Items      TypeA TypeB TypeC TypeD**
Bronze       1     0     0     1
Silver       0     0     1     0
Gold         0     1     1     0
Titanimum    1     0     0     0

And so, for this snapshot of table, I want to QUERY range to be *{A:A\B:B\C:C\D:D\E:E}*.

Is this doable? And how can I achieve or construct a dynamic QUERY range?

Thanks for everyone...

Answer (score 1):

You can remove columns from a range based on a criteria using the FILTER command.

**Unfiltered**

```
Items   TypeA   TypeB   TypeC   TypeD   TypeE   TypeF   TypeG
Bronze  1        0       0       1       0       0        1
Silver  1        1       0       1       0       0        1
Gold    1        0       0       1       0       0        1
Titan   1        0       0       1       1       0        1
1       4        1       0       4       1       0        4
```

**Filtered to remove columns with total of 0**

```
Items   TypeA   TypeB   TypeD   TypeE   TypeG       
Bronze  1       0       1       0       1       
Silver  1       1       1       0       1       
Gold    1       0       1       0       1       
Titan   1       0       1       1       1
```

The 'trick' is to sum the sum the column data (for your example) and then test for >0

The filter expression is:

```
=FILTER(A1:H5,A6:H6 >0)
```

By way of explanation:

`A1:H5`  is the range to be filtered;
`A6:H6 >0`  selects all columns that have a value > 0 in row 6

I placed a 1 in A6 to make sure colA is included.

You can now do queries on the range returned by the above expression.